# Hibernate Criteria equivalent to the SQL query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a requirement where I need to find all the rows older than 180 days from a table. For that, I have written the below SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 
(EXTRACT (DAY  FROM (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - UPDATE_TS))) > 180
```

In the above query, **UPDATE_TS** is a column that stores the timestamp for each row.

I ran the above query in Oracle which returns me the required result.

I am using Hibernate for my data persistence, so i want to do the same using Hibernate Criteria API's. I haven't worked much in Hibernate so finding it a bit difficult to do it.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: I'm wondering if you cannot just simply use `select .. where sysdate - update_ts > 180`, then the criteria would be easy to build.

Comment: I want to do with Hibernate Criteria API. though I can use sql query if unable to do that with Criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can get one of CURRENT_DATE | CURRENT_TIME | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for date/time operations in JPQL. I did not see `EXTRACT` usage in any implementations. So you might want to compare days directly perhaps ? Check [JPQL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_datetime) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate query language will be ideal for you.

```
from YourEntity e where (day(current_date()) - day(e.myDate)) > 180
```

I'm not tested this HQL but something similar should work. Read about HQL: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html